# How to mix Native Addon and Modules?

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon

I developed a wrapper for a C++ library using [node-addon-api](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api).
I'd like to export some node functions with those C++ functions.

Some functions can be coded in Javascript and don't require to be coded in C++.

```cpp
Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
    exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "hello"), Napi::Function::New(env, Hello));
    return exports;
}
```

**How can we mix napi and nodeJs functions?**

Comment: What does "I'd like to export some node functions." mean in this context?  If you're trying to export some functions that when called will call into your C++ code, there's a simple example [here](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_hello_world) and other more complicated examples following later on that page.  Not sure what you're asking for beyond that.

Comment: I want some functions to be run in javascript exclusively. Modules + Addon combined together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no problem to mix "native" functions and pure JS functions.

Assuming you have an `index.js` in your project which serves as your main file

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "mixedModule",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A mixture of functions created via C++ or JS",
  "main": "index.js",
  "typings": "index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
  ...
  }
}
```

you are free to decide which functions you want to (re-)export:

```js
const nativeModule = require("bindings")("myModule.node");

function jsFunction() {
    ...
}

module.exports = {
  nativeFunction: nativeModule.nativeFunction,
  jsFunction
}
```